# Which one is correct between map and mapVal when I use Delegates in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

The Code B is from webpage. In my mind ,it should be Code A, right?

**Code A**

```
class User(val map: Map<String, Any?>) {
    val name: String by map
    val age: Int     by map
}
```

**Code B**

```
class User(val map: Map<String, Any?>) {
    val name: String by Delegates.mapVal(map)
    val age: Int     by Delegates.mapVal(map)
}
```

**Code For Both**

```
val user = User(mapOf (
    "name" to "John Doe",
    "age" to 25
))
```

Comment: The example you labeled as **Code A** is the standard way of doing this as far as I know

Comment: Thanks! Is Code B wrong ?

Comment: There is no such thing as `Delegates.mapVal` in the current version of Kotlin, but it might have existed before. Maybe the example is old, or `mapVal` was defined as an extension function for the `Delegates` class

Comment: Nicolas is correct, you can read more at https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/delegated-properties.html

Comment: Thanks! https://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/2013/06/kotlin-m5-3-idea-13-delegated-properties-and-more/ use `by Delegates.mapVal()`

Comment: The blog post describes a version of Kotlin that existed 2.5 years before the 1.0 release. A lot of things have changed in the meantime.